# C言語とC++言語、C#言語の違いが知りたい

Tags: c#, c++, c

コンピューターでよく使われている言語に関して分からないことがあります。

C, C++, そしてUnityで使われている C# にはどの様な違いがありますか。
どの言語も "C" と言う文字があるので同じように見えるのですが…

Answer (score 4):

C言語にはクラスの概念がありません。C言語にクラスの概念を追加したのがC++です。
C言語系の構文でインクリメントを表すのが++ですが、C言語をインクリメントしたという
意味でC++と名付けられたのだと思います。
C#は元々マイクロソフトが開発した言語ですが、C++をより良くしようとの考えから、
C++をさらにインクリメントしてC++ ++とし、++ ++を縦に並べてC#になったようです。
従いまして、言語の構文的にはC#が一番進んでることになります。
ただし、C#は.NET用の言語として開発されていますので、ネイティブではC言語、
C++を使うことになります。

Answer (score 2):

C言語は最も古い言語で、現在は主に組み込み/IoT分野/ドライバ作成の一部で使われます。
class等の文法がなく、引数なし関数の引数にvoidを記載（古い文法の名残）します。

C++は、主に速度が重視される一部の環境やライブラリの作成や、ゲーム開発分野で使用されます。

C#は、いまでこそUnity（mono framework系）で採用された言語ですが、
それ以外ではWindows上の.NET Framework上で動くことを前提とした.NET言語の1つです。
Windows用のexeまたはWindows ServerのIIS上のASP.NETとしてWebシステムを作るのに使用されます。
（※Linux上でASP.NETを動かすために移植された.NET Coreは存在しますが、
業務で使用しているのを見たことはいまだにありません）

使用される分野は全く異なるので、最初は目指したいものから選ぶべきだと思います。

Comment: C言語の場合、今も引数なし関数にはvoidを書かなければならないと思いますが、いつから変わったのでしょう？

Comment: すいません、確認しましたが今でも書きますね。記載を訂正しておきます。